# AngularJS Directive not working to simply add a H3 tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to move code out of my index.html and have it inserted with directives to provide better DRY and SOLID development processes.  I have a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P11jBXpvL3gRh2A7xBDK?p=preview) illustrating a simple test.  I do not appear to get any errors outside the errors from the Plunker editor, but the directive does not insert the simple H3 example test.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);

angular.module('MyApp').directive('MainMenu', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Hello World</h3>',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casing that you use for defining directives differs from the casing you use when using it in your markup.

When defining it, you use `camelCase`. e.g. `angular.module('MyApp').directive('mainMenu', ...`.

When using it in markup, you use `dash-case`. e.g. `<main-menu></main-menu>`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried it previously with the camel case, but it was not working.  The extra piece of the dash in the name is what corrected it.  Thanks. +1

Answer (score 2):

You have called the wrong directive name.

Please try this:

**JS**

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);

angular.module('MyApp').directive('mainMenu', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Hello World</h3>',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<main-menu></main-menu>
```

Link demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nRNlvY8ggg47H7OuYuyn?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried it previously with the camel case, but it was not working.  @GregL had the extra piece of the dash in the name, similar to your plunker as well.  Thanks for the answer. +1